# Get length of Impala table varchar columns from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, impala

Try to get in Spark length of varchar columns, declared in following Impala table:

```
show create table dev_dm_rco.f102
```

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE dev_dm_rco.f102 (
  rep_id INT,
  msr_prd_id INT,
  ...
  bank_code VARCHAR(9),
  tu_cd VARCHAR(2),
  pl_stmt_num VARCHAR(5)'
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  report_date VARCHAR(50)
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION ...
TBLPROPERTIES ('spark.sql.create.version'='2.2 or prior', 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols'='1', 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1'...)
```

First try- using Spark API:

```
String f102SqlQuery = "select * from dev_dm_rco.f102";

Dataset<Row> f102Dataset = SparkService.sql(f102SqlQuery);

for(StructField sf:f102Dataset.schema().fields())
log.info("f102dataset sf.name()="+sf.name()+" sf.dataType().typeName()="+sf.dataType().typeName());
```

Varchar columns returned as string without length:

```
f102dataset sf.name()=rep_id sf.dataType().typeName()=integer
f102dataset sf.name()=msr_prd_id sf.dataType().typeName()=integer
...
f102dataset sf.name()=bank_code sf.dataType().typeName()=string
...
f102dataset sf.name()=tu_cd sf.dataType().typeName()=string
f102dataset sf.name()=pl_stmt_num sf.dataType().typeName()=string
f102dataset sf.name()=report_date sf.dataType().typeName()=string
```

Second try- using `show create table`:

```
String f102CreateTable = "show create table dev_dm_rco.f102";
Dataset<Row> crtF102Stmt = sqlContext.sql(f102CreateTable);

log.info(f102CreateTable+": "+ crtF102Stmt.collectAsList());
```

Again all varchar columns returned as string with no length:

```
show create table dev_dm_rco.f102: 
[[CREATE TABLE `dev_dm_rco`.`f102`
(`rep_id` int, 
 `msr_prd_id` int, 
 ...
 `bank_code` string, 
 `tu_cd` string, 
 `pl_stmt_num` string')
PARTITIONED BY (`report_date` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  
)
STORED AS
  INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime' = '1596083577'
)
]]
```

Is there any way to get length of varchar fields declared in Impala table, using Spark?
Spark version: 2.3.1
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
show column stats dev_dm_rco.f102
```

for each column, it should return col name, data type, #distinct values, #nulls, max size/varchar length, and avg size/varchar length

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use show column stats <db_name>.<table_name>;

If you are using CDP and you are seeing negative values or such, you can just compute stats on that table and try the same again.